# How do parentheses work with custom data types?

Tags: parsing, haskell, operators, expression, parentheses

Currently, I am working on a problem of parsing and showing expressions in Haskell.

```
type Name = String
data Expr = Val Integer
          | Var Name
          | Expr :+: Expr
          | Expr :-: Expr
          | Expr :*: Expr
          | Expr :/: Expr
          | Expr :%: Expr
```

This is the code of my data type Expr and this is how i define show function:

```
instance Show Expr where
  show (Val x) = show x
  show (Var y) = y
  show (p :+: q) = par (show p ++ "+" ++ show q)
  show (p :-: q) = par (show p ++ "-" ++ show q)
  show (p :/: q) = par (show p ++ "/" ++ show q)
  show (p :*: q) = par (show p ++ "*" ++ show q)
  show (p :%: q) = par (show p ++ "%" ++ show q)

par :: String -> String
par s = "(" ++ s ++ ")"
```

Later i tried to transform string input into the expression but i encounter the following problem: I don't understand how parentheses in the second case are implemented in Haskell.

```
*Main> Val 2 :*:Val 2 :+: Val 3 
((2*2)+3)
*Main> Val 2 :*:(Val 2 :+: Val 3) 
(2*(2+3))
```

Because of that, i am a bit confused regarding how should i transform parentheses from my string into the expression. Currently i am using the following function for parsing, but for now, it just ignores parentheses which is not intended behavior:

```
toExpr :: String -> Expr
toExpr str = f (lexer str) (Val 0)
   where 
    f [] expr = expr
    f (c:cs) expr
     |isAlpha (head c)  = f cs (Var c)
     |isDigit (head c)  = f cs (Val (read c))
     |c == "+"  = (expr :+: f cs (Val 0))
     |c == "-"  = (expr :-: f cs (Val 0))
     |c == "/"  = (expr :/: f cs (Val 0))
     |c == "*"  = (expr :*: f cs (Val 0))
     |c == "%"  = (expr :%: f cs (Val 0))
     |otherwise = f cs expr
```

Edit: few grammar mistakes

Comment: Barring fixity declarations (using `infixl`, `infixr` or `infix`), your operators all will have precedence 9 (the same as `!!` and `.`) and be left-associative. However, that has nothing to do with the precedence and associative you assign to operators in your parsed language. Your `toExpr` function can handle these in whichever way you want regardless of the precedence or associativity of `:+:` and co.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand how parentheses in the second case are implemented in Haskell.

The brackets just give precedence to a certain part of the expression to parse. The problem is not with the parenthesis you render. I think the problem is that you did *not* assign precedence to your operators. This thus means that, unless you specify brackets, Haskell will consider all operators to have the same precedence, and parse these left-to-right. This thus means that *x ⊕ y ⊗ z* is parsed as *(x ⊕ y) ⊗ z*.

You can define the precedence of your `:+:`, `:*`, etc. operators with `infixl`:

```
infixl 7 :*:, :/:, :%:
infixl 5 :+:, :-:

type Name = String
data Expr = Val Integer
          | Var Name
          | Expr :+: Expr
          | Expr :-: Expr
          | Expr :*: Expr
          | Expr :/: Expr
          | Expr :%: Expr
```

As for your parser (the `toExpr`), you will need a parsing mechanism like a [*LALR parser* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR_parser) that stores results on a stack, and thus makes proper operations.

Comment: While that's true, this won't affect the result of `toExpr` at all, so I don't think this helps with OP's actual problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as sepp2k mentioned, unfortunately, it does not help with my initial problem since even with addition of infixl after my toExpr parsing it is still parsed left to right.

Comment: @ArsenyNikonov: the parsing indeed is not affected, since you do that manually. I think you here should use an LL, LR, or LALR parser that uses a stack for intermediate results.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

This was my final parser which gave me the result I needed. To get the result i wanted proper grammar was added and i wrote a parses according to he grammar. 
Thanks, everyone for the help.

```
{-
  parser for the following grammar:
  E  -> T E'
  E' -> + T E' | - T E' | <empty string>
  T  -> F T'
  T' -> * F T' | / F T' | % F T' | <empty string>
  F  -> (E) | <integer> | <identifier> 
-}

parseExpr :: String -> (Expr,[String])
parseExpr tokens = parseE (lexer tokens)

parseE :: [String] -> (Expr,[String])
parseE tokens = parseE' acc rest where (acc,rest) = parseT tokens

parseE' :: Expr -> [String] -> (Expr,[String])
parseE' accepted ("+":tokens) = let (acc,rest) = parseT tokens in parseE' (accepted :+: acc) rest
parseE' accepted ("-":tokens) = let (acc,rest) = parseT tokens in parseE' (accepted :-: acc) rest
parseE' accepted tokens = (accepted,tokens)

parseT :: [String] -> (Expr,[String])
parseT tokens = let (acc,rest) = parseF tokens in parseT' acc rest

parseT' :: Expr -> [String] -> (Expr,[String])
parseT' accepted ("*":tokens) = let (acc,rest) = parseF tokens in parseT' (accepted :*: acc) rest
parseT' accepted ("/":tokens) = let (acc,rest) = parseF tokens in parseT' (accepted :/: acc) rest
parseT' accepted ("%":tokens) = let (acc,rest) = parseF tokens in parseT' (accepted :%: acc) rest
parseT' accepted tokens = (accepted,tokens)

parseF :: [String] -> (Expr,[String])
parseF ("(":tokens) = (e, tail rest) where (e,rest) = parseE tokens 
parseF (t:tokens)
  | isAlpha (head t) = (Var t,tokens)
  | isDigit (head t) = (Val (read t),tokens)
  | otherwise = error ""
parseF [] = error ""


lexer :: String -> [String]
lexer [] = []
lexer (c:cs)
  | elem c " \t\n"        = lexer cs   
  | elem c "=+-*/%()" = [c]:(lexer cs)
  | isAlpha c             = (c:takeWhile isAlpha cs):lexer(dropWhile isAlpha cs)
  | isDigit c             = (c:takeWhile isDigit cs):lexer(dropWhile isDigit cs)
  | otherwise             = error ""
```